# Traverse all elements of a "root element which is a ComplexType", in a xsd file in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I need help to traverse all elements in a xsd file. I am new to this subject. I am pasting the below example code what ever I have worked till now.

First of all I am simply loading the xsd file( as shown in the snippet) into xml schema, then I need to traverse the elements in the root element.

```
XmlSchema xsd = XmlSchema.Read(new StreamReader(AppKeysManager.ConfigurationMasterFolder + @"\Parameters.xsd"), null);
var xss = new XmlSchemaSet();
xss.Add(xsd);
xss.Compile();

foreach (DictionaryEntry item in xsd.Elements)
{
    rootElement = item.Value as XmlSchemaElement; break;
}
```

Snippet of what my xsd looks like

```
<xs:complexType name="Parameters">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="A">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="mstns:Restricted8CharString">
              <xs:attribute name="Caption" use="required" fixed="Caption for A">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="ActionWhenMaxReached" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
                    <xs:pattern value="[1-3]"></xs:pattern>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="Expression" type="xs:string" default="0" />
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="B">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:short">
              <xs:attribute name="Caption" use="prohibited">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="ActionWhenMaxReached" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
                    <xs:pattern value="[1-3]"></xs:pattern>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="Expression" type="xs:string" default="0" />
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType name="Parameters">
```

Comment: @Richard can I even have a clue why am I given a negative reputation, although I have given an answer to my question?

Comment: I dont think you've been given negative reputation I think you've lost positive reputation. I think a moderator will have deleted your answer saying "ive put the amswer in the question" because it wasnt an answer. If you can self answer a question thats excellent, post it as the answer. Ive put your answer (from the question) as a community wiki (that avoids me unfairly getting positive reputation for your work) but feel free to repost it as your own answer if you wish

Comment: @RichardTingle well whatever You may say, I only see a -ve in my reputation (and that is how I see it), which is not good. In spite of being giving answer, as for as the "Ive put the answer in the question" is concerned, I did it so that any other user may not have to scroll down and see the answer :)

Comment: Well I was planning on upvoting any real answer you posted but if you'd rather be angry about it thats fine too. Remember this is a Q&A site, the question part is for questions the answer part is for answers, anything else is liable to be removed

Comment: Yeah, thats not the way stack overflow does things. Answers go in an answer. This is good for you too because people can seperately upvote your question(at +5) and answer (at +10) instead of just +5. Equally if other people also posted an answer that would be judged along side your answer rather than your answer having some wierd, up the top status

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you inner elements as well as their attributes

```
XmlSchema xsd = XmlSchema.Read(new StreamReader(pathToxsdFile), null);


var xss = new XmlSchemaSet();
    xss.Add(xsd);
    xss.Compile();

    XmlSchemaElement rootElement = null;
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in xsd.Elements)
    {
        rootElement = item.Value as XmlSchemaElement; break;
    }

    XmlSchemaComplexType innerContent = rootElement.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;
    var innerContentsOfRoot = innerContent.Particle as XmlSchemaAll;

    foreach (XmlSchemaElement item in innerContentsOfRoot.Items)
    {
        XmlSchemaComplexType moreInnerContent = item.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

        foreach (DictionaryEntry item2 in moreInnerContent.AttributeUses)
        {
            if (string.Compare(((XmlSchemaAttribute)(item2.Value)).Name, attributeName, true) == 0)
            {
                string captionName = ((XmlSchemaAttribute)(item2.Value)).FixedValue;

            }
        }
    }
```